# asp.net listbox_index changed postback is firing on every button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

I have a listbox that is populating on a buttonclick and then when the user selects or changes the index on the listbox it downloads a file related to it.

The problem I have is when they go to push a button to search a new record it downloads the file again but firing the code below again. How can I stop it from calling the postback on other buttons?

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string splitval = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string[] newvar = splitval.Split(',');
    GlobalVariables.attachcrq = newvar[0];
    GlobalVariables.num = UInt32.Parse(newvar[1]);
    string filename = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    GlobalVariables.ARSServer.GetEntryBLOB("CHG:WorkLog", GlobalVariables.attachcrq, GlobalVariables.num, Server.MapPath("~/TEMP/") + filename);

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/TEMP/" + filename));
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(file.Extension.ToLower());
    Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`IsPostback` property should be used over here.

Enclose your code in condition `if(!Page.Ispostback)`

**Following can be the approach:**

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

       if(!Page.IsPostback)
      {
        string splitval = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string[] newvar = splitval.Split(',');
        GlobalVariables.attachcrq = newvar[0];
        GlobalVariables.num = UInt32.Parse(newvar[1]);
        string filename = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        GlobalVariables.ARSServer.GetEntryBLOB("CHG:WorkLog", GlobalVariables.attachcrq, GlobalVariables.num, Server.MapPath("~/TEMP/") + filename);

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/TEMP/" + filename));
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(file.Extension.ToLower());
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
      }
    }
```

**MSDN Referance For IsPostBack:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

**Usage With Example:**

http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/60291

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: How will this code ever execute then? The listbox is populated after a button click, at which point and for future postbacks !Page.IsPostback will never be true

Comment: its now not running the code at all when i change the index, it just flashes

Comment: try setting AutoPostBack='true' to your listbox

Comment: @CRice but op wants to do it only for SelectedIndexChanged event, it will populate the list on load or other events

Comment: simply op would have to make the function for this code and call from different positions wherever he wants, then , there will be no issues of ispostback execution

Comment: or, with AutoPostBack='true' is also good alternative provided by you.

Comment: maybe postback is the wrong method, i just want the event to fire when somes one clicks on the listbox item. how could i do that?

Comment: So, keep the SelectedIndexChanged event, remove the IsPostBack check, add AutoPostBack='true' to the listbox declaration.

Comment: thats what i ahve right now, but it is firing the postback on every button press not indexchange only..

Comment: Then, can you update your question to show listbox aspx code, and initialization code (where its datasource is set up).  You probably want to bind it on !IsPostback

Comment: if i comment out the response.clear to response.end section it works perfectly,  so somethings wrong in the code there. Ill have to see why that section keeps firing on postback.